# Having trouble finding position in array via binary search

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary-search, bubble-sort

I'm having trouble searching my array for a value the user inputs. This project is about taking money from your friends and investing it. The program is to keep track of those investments. I use an array to assign each friend's investment. I import a file called investments.txt, and this is needed for this code to compile.

My problem is the binary search itself. I know my array is valid, and it is sorted via bubble sort. And that all works, so no problems there, but for some reason unknown to me, or at least I can't see it, every time i search a value in my array (a valid value from the txt file import) it considers it "Not found!". It won't print valid info to the user, I'm not sure why.

Example on what the output must look like:

Would you like to search for a investment amount? (Y/N) Y

Enter investment amount: 10075.45

Investment amount 10075.45 is found at position 34.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to search for an investment amount? (Y/N)");

    String answer= in.nextLine();//Prompt the user for binary search

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        System.out.println("Enter the investment amount");
        double userSrc = in.nextDouble();

        int n = 0;
        int first = 0;
        int last = n - 1;
        int middle = (first+last)/2;

           while (first <= last) {
              if (fileArray[middle] < userSrc)
                 first = middle + 1;    
              else if (fileArray[middle] == userSrc) {
                 System.out.printf("%f found at location %d.\n", userSrc, middle+1);
                 return;
              }
              else
                 last = middle - 1;

              middle = (first + last)/2;
           }
           if (first > last)
              System.out.printf("Not found! %f isn't present in the list.\n", userSrc);

           return;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made the section of code smaller. The main problem I'm having is when I input an investment amount from the text file that is imported, it just says "Not found" even though the amount is correct and in the array. For example, in my text file I have $142.15  as an investment, and stored in the array correctly, but when I binary search for it, it spits out my "Not Found!" statement. I don't know why.

Comment: If it's not finding a value, then it's probably failing to look in the right place.  You can easily determine where it's looking by printing out the value of 'middle' (and fileArray[middle]) each time you go round the loop.  This should give you insight as to where the code is not doing what you expect.   At the same time, I'm suspicious of anything requiring exact floating-point equality.

Comment: As far as I can tell by debugging and doing as you said, the code seems to not even register the "else if" statement at all. If you don't mind, could you take another look and check the syntax? I'm lost to what's wrong. It's getting info from the right place. My array is fileArray, do I need to create a method for this to work with a new array or something? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Your code doesn’t even compile so how can it have any behaviour, correct or incorrect. This does not compile: `double[] fileArray = {"5", "100", "146.15", "314.56", "600.92"};`.    You cannot assign an array of String to a variable of type `double[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the simplified code. The example you made was missing a few things that I promptly added in to get it to compile.

In past edits you included

```
double[] fileArray = {"5", "100", "146.15", "314.56", "600.92"};
```

Which isn't bad, test data is required. This didn't need to be removed from the question, it needed the quotations around the values to be removed so they could be treated as proper doubles. With that in mind, it seems that you accidentally initialized `int n = 0` instead of `int n = fileArray.length`. This seems like it was the problem on both edits of the program. Remember that n is supposed to be the amount of elements you have stored in the array when it comes to this method of sorting, so having it at 0 will cause all of the other values to be initialized incorrectly and treat it like there's 0 elements in the array. Here's my corrected code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class binarysearch{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double[] fileArray = {5, 100, 146.15, 314.56, 600.92};
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to search for an investment amount? (Y/N)");

        String answer= in.nextLine();//Prompt the user for binary search

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the investment amount");
            double userSrc = in.nextDouble();

            int n = fileArray.length;
            int first = 0;
            int last = n - 1;
            int middle = (first+last)/2;
            while (first <= last) {
                if (fileArray[middle] < userSrc)
                    first = middle + 1;    
                else if (fileArray[middle] == userSrc) {
                    System.out.printf("%f found at location %d.\n", userSrc, middle+1);
                    //return;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    last = middle - 1;

                    middle = (first + last)/2;
            }
            if (first > last)
                System.out.printf("Not found! %f isn't present in the list.\n", userSrc);

            //return;
            System.out.println("Would you like to search for an investment amount? (Y/N)");
            answer= in.nextLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output for `Y 146.15`:

```
Would you like to search for an investment amount? (Y/N)
Enter the investment amount
146.150000 found at location 3.
```

Finally, notice that your program returns after finding one value. This return is still in main so it exits the program. This will cause the loop of prompting users to never get anywhere. I would replace this with a `break;` to exit ONLY the loop and remove the one at the end of the loop entirely. There might also be hanging newlines from the `nextDouble` calls you might want to look out for. I will leave that for you to play around with. Maybe even try with inputs like `146.150000000001`.

Comment: Wow! so my big problem was literally n = 0....Man I messed up. I can't believe this, I spent 2 days, I went through about 3 iterations of this segment of code and I missed that one simple error. I fixed the other things you mentioned, and I added .2%d to print proper decimal. All in all it works perfectly thanks to you guys. Thanks a bunch Patrick.